# Showing value of multiple selected checkboxes and the form assiciated with them as JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, fetch-api

I am pretty new to javascript and am also trying out fetch api to interact with backend. I have made some checkboxes whose value I want to store in an array (in json format) if they are selected and also the values that will be entered in the input boxes and then sent that array to the backend using fetch api so that it can be used to do the processing. Can anyone please help me out here.

```js
$("#step1").click(function() {
  $("#checked1").css("display", "initial");
  $("#checked1").toggle($(this).prop("checked"));
});
      
$("#step2").click(function() {
  $("#checked2").css("display", "initial");
  $("#checked2").toggle($(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Ready to start </p>
<div class="form-check checkbox-rounded checkbox-filled">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="Yes" name="demo" id="Yes">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="Yes">Yes</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check checkbox-rounded checkbox-filled">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="step1" name="demo" id="step1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="step1">Check to start step1</label>

   <div id ="checked1" style="padding-left:20px; display: none;" class="custom-control-inline">

    <input type="text" id="inputValue" class="form-control form-centrol-sm" style="width: 60%; display: inherit;" placeholder="Enter your name">
      <hr style="margin-top: 0.5rem !important; margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-check checkbox-rounded checkbox-filled">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="step2" name="demo" id="step2">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="step2">Check to start step2</label>

     <div id ="checked2" style="padding-left:20px; display: none;" class="custom-control-inline">
     <input type="text" id="inputValue" class="form-control form-centrol-sm" style="width: 60%; display: inherit;" placeholder="Enter your age">
      <hr style="margin-top: 0.5rem !important; margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, have you checked [serialize?](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Do some research, and give it a try. When your efforts appear fruitless return here to ask why your code is not working or what you might be doing wrong. You'll learn so much more and it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: You're already using jQuery, why not just use `$.ajax`? Why does it have to be the Fetch API?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is how you get the values into the array. If you update your question to also show how you are planning to use the fetch api, I'll update my answer to include it as well.

I have it as an array like your question required but I'd recommend using an object instead because that's what JSON is -- JavaScript Object Notation.

```js
$("#step1").click(function() {
  $("#checked1").css("display", "initial");
  $("#checked1").toggle($(this).prop("checked"));
});
      
$("#step2").click(function() {
  $("#checked2").css("display", "initial");
  $("#checked2").toggle($(this).prop("checked"));
});

$('input').on('input', () =>{
  let dataArray = [ 
    "Yes checked: " + ($("#Yes").is(':checked')),
    "step1 checked: " + ($("#step1").is(':checked')),
    "step1 value: " + ($("#checked1Input").val() === "" ? "Not entered" : $("#checked1Input").val()),
    "step2 checked: " + ($("#step2").is(':checked')),    
    "step2 value: " + ($("#checked2Input").val() === "" ? "Not entered" : $("#checked2Input").val())
  ];
  
  let dataObject = {
  "Yes checked" : ($("#Yes").is(':checked')),
    "step1 checked" : ($("#step1").is(':checked')),
    "step1 value" : ($("#checked1Input").val() === "" ? "Not entered" : $("#checked1Input").val()),
    "step2 checked" : ($("#step2").is(':checked')),    
    "step2 value" : ($("#checked2Input").val() === "" ? "Not entered" : $("#checked2Input").val())  
  };
  
  let jsonArrayString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
  let jsonObjectString = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
  console.clear();
  console.log("As an array: ", jsonArrayString);
  console.log("As an object: ", jsonObjectString);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Ready to start </p>
<div class="form-check checkbox-rounded checkbox-filled">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="Yes" name="demo" id="Yes">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="Yes">Yes</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check checkbox-rounded checkbox-filled">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="step1" name="demo" id="step1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="step1">Check to start step1</label>

   <div id ="checked1" style="padding-left:20px; display: none;" class="custom-control-inline">

    <input type="text" id="checked1Input" class="form-control form-centrol-sm" style="width: 60%; display: inherit;" placeholder="Enter your name">
      <hr style="margin-top: 0.5rem !important; margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-check checkbox-rounded checkbox-filled">
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filled-in" value="step2" name="demo" id="step2">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="step2">Check to start step2</label>

     <div id ="checked2" style="padding-left:20px; display: none;" class="custom-control-inline">
     <input type="text" id="checked2Input" class="form-control form-centrol-sm" style="width: 60%; display: inherit;" placeholder="Enter your age">
      <hr style="margin-top: 0.5rem !important; margin-bottom: 0.5rem !important;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I  will not be using fetch as of now so my problem is solved with the code provided by you only.